# SQL ORDER BY arrival AND departure time, good order

Tags: sql

[image: On the left the arrival time // on the right departure time]

I'would like to order the departure time in the good order.
In the picture 20:02 and 22:12 departure time  should be after the 20:20 arrival time.
the 20:02 depature time has another arrival date that's why is not displayed in the table.

My SQL:

```
  "SELECT * FROM flights WHERE arrdate = '$date' or depdate = '$date' ORDER BY   eta ASC";
```

How to Order arrival and departure time on the good order ?

Thank you

Comment: you will need to order by date as well, not just the time of day

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you mean by the term “good order”. Also include the result you want to achieve based on the sample data and the logic rules you’ve applied to achieve that result

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `.. ORDER BY  coalesce(eta, etd) asc;`